# Reduce Avatar Progress

Tags: xcom-2

Is there any way to reduce the avatar progress on a regular basis?  I've had 2 missions that reduced it by one pip, but they seemed to be fairly random and part of a dark event.   Now I get 3 missions with dark events at a time and none have a reduction.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255807/does-the-first-black-site-mission-provided-reset-the-advent-project-countdown-ti

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The progression of the avatar project is "collected" in the "alien facility" sites which look like this on the global map:

[image: alien facility]

When you successfully attack such a facility, the aliens lose the progress from that facility and they have to build a new one in a different region. As you can see by the red square below it, the facility in this screenshot has only collected one point yet, so it is not yet a priority. But before you can attack a facility, you have to establish contact with the local resistance of the region. This isn't done with the region of this facility yet, so I should better do that soon so I can take out that facility quickly when the aliens get close to completion.

The facility in the pacific ocean which you see as soon as you become aware of the avatar project can not be attacked (yet!). It represents any project progress which is not bound to a specific facility.

Avatar progress can also be reduced by events which will happen when you progress in the "Alien Blacksite" and "Codex" story arcs.

Comment: That last facility you mention is kind of a spoiler (use spoiler text?). I'm not 100% positive on this, but I think that researching stolen facility leads can allow you to attack facilities without first having made contact with the local resistance in the facility region.

Comment: Skullmining ADVENT troops can sometimes grant a facility's location for assault even without first establishing comms.

Answer (score 3):

You can attack a facility in a region you have not contacted, given the correct circumstances. This requires you to acquire a "mission lead to alien facility" or whatever it's called. This can be gotten at least from a hack reward or sometimes you can buy it from Black Market.

Then you have to research it. It's a quick research but it also takes some intel to do so. After the research it is possible that it does not reveal a new facility on the map, but instead "gives you the exact coordinates" for a facility of which whereabouts you already knew about but did not attack due to not having contact in the corresponding region.

If that happens, you can actually fly over there and attack the place even with no contact. Or you can click its button on the bottom of the screen in the geoscape view (you can also see from the looks of the icon that it's unlocked now). I guess the flavor is such that when you researched the coordinates, you no longer need the local resistance to inform about the exact location of the facility.

I had this happen to me two days ago. I had an alien facility in Australia but I had no contact there. I previously had gotten a facility lead from a hack reward and decided to research it because avatar progress was almost maxed out. When it finished, I was disappointed because it only "revealed" the site in Australia I already knew about. I thought I wasted the intel, but on closer inspection I noticed its icon had changed (I had another unreachable alien facility next to it), and I was able to fly there and give it an X-4 treatment.

Comment: I haven't run into this yet, although it certainly sounds plausible. You don't say how you got this information (I assume it's from personal experience, but you should say so). Have you had this happen to you? How often?

Comment: I had this happen to me two days ago. I had an alien facility in Australia but I had no contact there. I previously had gotten a facility lead from a hack reward and decided to research it because avatar progress was almost maxed out. When it finished, I was disappointed because it only "revealed" the site in Australia I already knew about. I thought I wasted the intel, but on closer inspection I noticed its icon had changed (I had another unreachable alien facility next to it), and I was able to fly there and give it an X-4 treatment.

Comment: Actually, according to this reddit thread (https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/45ajg2/what_a_facility_lead_does_exactly/), all this research does is let you go attack a facility in a region you have no contact with. It will never reveal a new facility, which is a bit odd considering how it's worded.

Comment: I've had a facility lead highlight a base I was already aware of, but unfortunately that base was in a region I had made contact with already, so I think it really was wasted. Good to know there's something resembling a good reason for that happening.

Comment: I would call that more than odd, considering how it's worded. I would call that stupid.

Answer (score -1):

You can not attack a facility without first establishing contact. Doesn't matter what point in the game you are in. It's done that way to force you to invest in comms, and make the game more challenging.