# What's the consequence of the Advent completing the Avatar Project in XCOM2?

Tags: xcom-2

[image]

It seams inevitable that the Advent will complete the Avatar Project; am I supposed to be able to stop them, or is this just a count down timer.  I mean the graphic is *red* so I assume something bad is going to happen.

Should I bother even trying to stop them or instead focus on research and building up my soldiers / base?

I haven't progressed enough to find out what the Avatar Project *actually is,* so please mark any spoilers accordingly.

Comment: According to PCG, once the timer fills up you have 20 days to set back ADVENT before you lose. EDIT: First section on this page: http://www.pcgamer.com/xcom-2-guide/

Comment: Related question: [Reduce Avatar Progress](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254494/reduce-avatar-progress/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Once all 12 pips are filled, a timer starts (based on the next time Advent would generate a pip of progress ~20 days). If you haven't reduced any Avatar progress by that time, the game ends in a loss.

Attacking Alien facilities will be your primary way to reduce Avatar progress, so be sure to acquire the resistance connections that make launching blacksite missions possible.