# Does the first black site mission provided reset the Advent Project countdown timer?

Tags: xcom-2

I am drawing out attacking Advent "black sites" as long as possible to extend my preparation window for my troops.

Does the very first, game provided black site operation *(designated by a gold-ish colored factory icon)* reset the Advent countdown timer? Or does assaulting only the red designated facilities do this?

Comment: Find out how to reduce overall Avatar Project progress: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254494/reduce-avatar-progress

Comment: @DavidYell Already read that one, needed this specific Q, A'ed ;)

Comment: Yep, just linking them up for other folks who are looking for related information :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the Advent Blacksite mission reduces the Avatar-progress by 2 pips (Legend difficulty) and will stop the timer, if it's already running.

Other facilities will reduce the progress by the number of pips shown below the facility on the Geoscape.

Comment: It's was one pip on Veteran.

Comment: two pips on Veteran in WotC

Answer (score 1):

In the legendary game I just played, the clock did not reset.

I had 6 days left on the clock before doing the 1st game provided blacksite. A few minutes later Avatar got the 2 blocks back due to a dark event. And the clock was at 6 days - basically ending my game for me.